# How to render objects inside a string vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In Vue2, I have a string along the lines of the following in my component.

```
<template>
    <div><h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div v-html="testString"></div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "test-component",
        props: ['incoming'],        
        data: function() {
            return {
                testString: "";
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.testString = this.incoming;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And then when I do the following (with all the imports done correctly)

```
<template>
    <text-component :incoming="mycontent"></text-component>
</template>
<script>
import 'test-component' from './path/to/test-component.vue'
export default { // etc, just presume this bit is right, it's only psudo code
components: ['test-component'],
data() { return { mycontent: '' }},
created() {
    this.mycontent="I just want to <router-link to='/home' v-html='Go Home'></router-link>"
</script>
```

So now I want the first template with **testString** to render the **<router-link>** as if I had put it in myself directly.

I've tried **v-html** and **{{ }}** , in my test-component but I think i'm missing something. I'm pretty sure in Vue1 I would use **{{{ }}}**.

Can anyone help out? Thanks.

Comment: <text-component> should be <test-component>.... it's the passing on the __router-link__ from a string that I'm struggling with.

Comment: In that case, please use the edit link at the bottom left corner of the post to update the question

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation on v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html):

> Note that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates.

---

You should be using a [slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots) instead.

Add the slot to your testComponent:

```
<template>
  <div><h1>Hello World</h1>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
```

And then just put the content right in the `test-component` tag:

```
<template>
  <test-component>
    I just want to <router-link to='/home' v-html='Go Home'></router-link>
  </test-component>
</template>
```